# Как с помощью Django REST Framework настроить формат возвращаемого json'а так, чтобы выводились названия элемента, а не его primary key?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

У меня есть модель `User` из `django.contrib.auth.models` и модель `Habit`, описанная следующим образом

```
from django.db import models

class Habit(models.Model):
    habit_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'habits', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.habit_name
```

Также есть UserSerializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers    

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'habits']
```

Результатом работы `GET /api/users/all` будет вот такой json

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "username": "maxon",
        "habits": [
            2,
            3
        ]
    },
    {
        "username": "user1",
        "habits": []
    }
]
```

Проблема в том, что в поле `"habits"` выводятся ключи привычек, а нужно, чтобы выводились их названия `habit_name`. Что для этого нужно сделать?

Comment: Например, [так](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)

Comment: @zakiroof помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло добавить `habits = StringRelatedField()` следующим образом

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    habits = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'habits']
```